# Memtest86+ which DIMM is failing?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

First of all, I have no idea how to configure it.

I made a photo of the screen to show what I got so far.

[image: memtest86+ error screenshot]

My question is which of my 4 DIMMs is damaged?

Comment: A) could be none of your dimms are "damaged" slightly incorrect timing can have memtest86 show as error. B) if your running in dual you might only be able to get it down to 2 items.  C) how long did you run this for?    D) often the next step would be to select specific portions of the memory using the configuration  E) next step is to test single modules, which also means they are not running in dual, if it was flakey in dual but works as single there is nothing actually "damaged" with the ram.  1 error could be a fluke, if the same address errors again and again  it is damaged.

Comment: Simplest way: test each module by itself, harder answer, the module addressed for 4096MB - 6144MB so the 2nd one.  I presume you have 3 4GB modules, I don't know, which is the reason actual specifications in words is nice.

Comment: ATM i am running memtest for 7 1/2 hours. Pass:2 Errors:1 the best way is to test them all by them self?

Comment: Yes as stated.  You might find that running test (i think) 5 or is it 6 or 7 , one of those only instead of the whole slew of tests is a way to get more of the really difficult passes with less time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

memtest tests all of the memory and reports errors if encountered. It doesn't test which port the error was received on.
You need different software (usually vendor specific) to be able to tell which slot is producing the error.

You have to test each DIMM separately to see which one is causing the problem. If none report a problem, you may have a problem with your memory slots and you'll need to test those separately.
If even after that you don't encounter any problems, it may just have been a fluke. Usually when memory fails, you get more than 1 single error.